# Is it proper to re-throw the error in catch statement if there's a task to handle in the block in Java?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it's proper to re-throw the error if there's a task to handle in the `catch` block in Java like:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (Exception e) {
  doSomethingElse();
  throw e;
}
```

I've been told that just throwing the error itself is a bad practice(might be wrong) but in my case, there's a handling part for this up there and I just simply want to handle a specific task(`doSomethingElse` in this case) at this level and throw the error so I'm going for this approach. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: If you can handle the exception why re-throw it? If you can't handle it why catch it? If something needs to be done even if there is an exception which isn't handling the exception why not use finally?

Comment: Well, it probably depends on the exception and the task. A general rule of thumb would be to either handle or (re)throw an exception. However, there might be cases where you might need to do both. One such situation might that you need to rethrow the exception (or wrap it in another one) to inform the caller but still log it because the caller could run on a different machine (although that could be handled differently) . That being said, you should only do both (rethrow the exception and do something) if you know the implications.

Comment: @Juan `doSomethingElse()` is leaving a log about the exception so I chose to handle it in the catch block and the reason I do it at this class level is I want to execute the function(`doSomethingElse`) with a property value of this class

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would want to concentrate an error handling for particular error in one place. So you either do the entire error handling here and then do not re-throw your exception or just don't catch it and let it be caught in its original place in higher up levels and be treated fully there. Sometimes what is done that you catch a particular type of exception and then wrap it up in different Exception and that is an accepted behavior:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (IOException e) {
  doSomethingElse();
  throw new MyCustomException("My custom error message", e);
}
```

So your case seems to be a bad design. However, I don't want to rule it out 100% as it might be some really rare case where you might need to do something like this. But as a normal case I'd say it is a bad practice

Comment: The thing is the caused error `e` is declared as `Exception` type but it is just an interface and `e` has its own class type. The reason I took the approach is I want to leave a log with a property value of this class level but delicate the other task which depends on the error type to the higher up levels.

Comment: I think you'd only wrap the exception if there was meaning and purpose behind wrapping it. In this case, it doesn't seem like there is. If the only justification is "It's bad practice not to wrap it", then that's a fallacy. You'd wrap to hide implementation details or provide more details up to the caller, and it doesn't seem like either of those are true here since OP is interacting with an API that only throws a generic `Exception`.